Why is schwa considered 'one' sound when it can be pronounced many ways?
I have almost no linguistics knowledge, but apparently schwa is the 'A's in America, the the 'e' in problem, or the O in complete.
It's always an unstressed vowel and I guess it's like if you could put an 'h' at the end of the vowel, but that's still very ambiguous. I always assumed the IPA was meant to be less ambiguous for demonstrating pronunciation when it fact it seems like you can lose information from it. For example if I don't know how to pronounce Astronaut and I read æstrənɔːt , I don't know if that schwa is 'uh' (which it is), or 'eh', or 'ah'. Is that true, and if so, wouldn't it be better if each sound was represented by its own symbol? Why is it represented this way instead?

You might want to find out that transcription can be broad and narrow, that is, distinguishing less or more details of pronunciation. More often you see the broad transcription, and what you're looking for is the narrow one. On Linguistics SE there are several questions with answers about this issue, have a look here.

Are you sure you're not just imagining that those sounds are different while they really aren't, just because you see them written differently? Of course they could also differ because they actually do in your dialect, but in General American, AFAIK, they don't.

/ə/ just means it is not identified as any other vowel phoneme, not that it is consistently realized like [ə]. As seen in Flemming (2009), the phonetic quality of /ə/ varies greatly.
